# Flink Streaming messages per second

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have written the following code which consumes the messages from a KAFKA producer which continuously sends messages in JSON format. Can anyone help me how i can calculate the number of messages per second (Which will be the throughput for my set up)

```
public class FlinkStreamingJob {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // parse input arguments
    final ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

    if(parameterTool.getNumberOfParameters() < 4) {
        System.out.println("Missing parameters!\nUsage: Kafka --topic <topic> " +
                "--bootstrap.servers <kafka brokers> --zookeeper.connect <zk quorum> --group.id <some id>");
        return;
    }

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.getConfig().disableSysoutLogging();
    env.getConfig().setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(4, 10000));
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000); // create a checkpoint every 1 seconds
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(parameterTool); // make parameters available in the web interface
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);


    DataStream<String> messageStream = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(
                    parameterTool.getRequired("topic"),
                    new SimpleStringSchema(),
                    parameterTool.getProperties()));

    messageStream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String map(String value) throws Exception {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
            System.out.println("Time for streaming (ms): " +(System.currentTimeMillis() - json.getLong("Time")));

            return value;
        }
    });

    // write kafka stream to standard out
    messageStream.print();
    env.execute();

}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, Flink reports quite a few useful metrics, including `numRecordsInPerSecond` and `numRecordsOutPerSecond` for each operator and task. See the [metrics documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html#io) for more info on the built-in metrics, and look in the web UI and/or REST API for the data. Or you can export the metrics using one of the built-in [metrics reporters](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html#reporter).

Comment: I came across Accumulators. How about using them instead?

Comment: Yes, you could probably get something working with Accumulators. If you do, and find it preferable, it would be interesting to hear why.